# Extending Object.prototype breaks JavaScript for..in loops, which are used heavily in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, performance, google-maps, meteor

I am developing project in meteor. I need to find object key form object value. So I tried the below code, But browser freezed.

```
Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function( value ) {
    for( var prop in this ) {
        if( this.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
             if( this[ prop ] === value )
                 return prop;
        }
    }
}

var test = {
   key1: 42,
   key2: 'foo'
};

test.getKeyByValue( 42 );  // returns 'key1'
```

console log

`This site adds property <getKeyByValue> to Object.prototype. Extending Object.prototype breaks JavaScript for..in loops, which are used heavily in Google Maps API v3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console message says it all doesn't it. 
You probaly caused an infinte loop by doing this and breaking tte for..in loop mechanics.

Extending native objects prototypes is almost always a bad idea.

If you want data objects just make a dataobject for storage of data

```js
function SimpleMap() {
    this.list = {};
}
SimpleMap.prototype.getKeyByValue = function( value ) {
    for( var prop in this.list ) {
        if( this.list.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
             if( this.list[ prop ] === value )
                 return prop;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
SimpleMap.prototype.size = function() {
   var count = 0;
   for( var prop in this.list ) {
        if( this.list.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
             ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
SimpleMap.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    return this.size() === 0;
}
SimpleMap.prototype.empty = function() {
   this.list = {};
}
SimpleMap.prototype.put = function(key, value) {
    this.list[key] = value;
}
SimpleMap.prototype.get = function(key) {
    return this.list[key];
}
SimpleMap.prototype.remove = function(key) {
    delete this.list[key];
}

var cars = new SimpleMap();
cars.put("volvo","vrooooom");
cars.put("citroen","frut frut frut");
cars.put("reliant","Darn you mr Bean");
var content = document.getElementById('frut');
content.appendChild(document.createTextNode("What does the reliant owner say? "+cars.get("reliant")));
content.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
content.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Who is vroooom? " + cars.getKeyByValue('vrooooom')));
content.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
content.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Is car storage empty? " + cars.isEmpty()));
cars.empty()
content.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
content.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Is the car storage empty now? " + cars.isEmpty()));
```

```html
<div id="frut">
</div>
```